# Creating factor-level indicator variables in R using spread or cast

Tags: r, reshape, dplyr, factors, tidyr

Assume a data structure like the following

```
MemberID <- c(123,123,234,234)
nbin <- 4
imatrix <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), size=nbin * length(MemberID), replace=TRUE), 
                  nrow=length(MemberID))
colnames(imatrix) <- letters[1:nbin]
years <- c("Y1","Y2","Y1","Y2")

mydf <- data.frame(cbind(MemberID, years, imatrix))
```

How can I make a similar data structure such that I have an indicator for each level of years for each a,b,c,d.

I would like to have a 2 x 9 data frame with columns MemberID, a.Y1, a.Y2, b.Y1,b.Y2,...

Ideally, I would like to do this with `spread` or `cast` as I have been using those tools a bit and would like to learn more about how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
reshape(mydf, timevar = "years", idvar= "MemberID", direction = "wide")
  MemberID a.Y1 b.Y1 c.Y1 d.Y1 a.Y2 b.Y2 c.Y2 d.Y2
1      123    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
3      234    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Solution using `reshape2` (and `magrittr`):

```
mydf %>% melt(c('MemberID','years')) %>% dcast(MemberID~...)
  MemberID Y1_a Y1_b Y1_c Y1_d Y2_a Y2_b Y2_c Y2_d
1      123    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
2      234    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'd love to a `tidyr` solution if any out there is feeling ambitious...

Answer (score 5):

Using `tidyr/dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(mydf, Var, Val, a:d) %>% 
             unite(yearsVar, years, Var) %>%
             spread(yearsVar, Val)
```